# How to reformat a razor (or html) page in visual studio 2022

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, razor-pages

I used Ctrl +K +D to reformat the c# code, but I can not find a way to do a similar task for HTML/Razor pages.

Is there any such capability in VS 2022 that automatically reformat HTML/Razor page?

Comment: Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D works for me for HTML/Razor files in VS2022. Perhaps you have an error in your markup?

Comment: @MikeBrind I do not think there is any problem with the HTML/Razor as the application runs properly and shows the correct output. Also, the HTML is simple and I can check it and it is valid.

Comment: Hi @mans , Do you have time to check my answer?

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT Thanks for your answer. It works on the code part of the page but not on the razor part of the page. So if I have a mall formatted <p> this is a test </p> it doesn't reformat it and make it clean.

Comment: @mans As written, Ctrl+A->Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D is the best choice, maybe you could add related hotkeys. If it helps you, you are welcome to accept it. If you want further functions, you need to go to the development community forum to make corresponding requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is not have any such capability in VS 2022 that automatically reformat HTML/Razor page.

`Ctrl+K`,`Ctrl+D` works for all these pages.

For code pages such as `c#`, you could open code clean to save and start automatically, and it will be automatically formatted.

[image]

Turn on the relevant format settings to automatically format the file during symbol completion.

[image]

`Ctrl+A`->`Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D` is the best choice, maybe you could add related hotkeys.